Compare attributes of JSON and then update the JSON where values are matched
I want to update an elasticsearch document. Each elasticsearch document contains a field named src_ip. I have another postgres database which contains two columns, named agent_ip and agent_id. NOW, I want that where src_ip and agent_ip is same,  then agent_id should be ingested in that elasticsearch document.
I have tried following processors for extracting elasticsearch data (src_ip):
1.SearchElasticsearch - to read the documents from an elasticsearch index
2.EvaluateJson - to fetch src_ip field from the documents
I have tried following processors for extracting data from postgres (agent_ip,agent_id)
1.ExecuteSQL - to fetch postgres data
2.ConvertAvroToJSON - to convert table data into JSON
Please tell how elasticsearch documents can be updated as described above

do you already have data in ES same as DB or both data are different ? do you know document id (_id) upfront or it is auto generated ?

Data in ES is different than data stored in db. However one field is same in both DBs. And document_id are autogenerated. I want to update ES in such a way that when src_ip is coming form ES, then for a prticular value of src_ip, value should be check in the other database, if values in both are same, then agent_id should be added in that ES document
